# xquery exclude certain files by underscore in file name

Tags: xquery

I have following collection structure

```
SCTA
 --lectio1
   --lectio1.xml
   --reims_lectio1.xml
   --sorb_lectio1.xml
 --lectio2
   --lectio2.xml
   --reims_lectio2.xml
   --sorb_lectio2.xml
```

Now using Xquery, I want to search only the files that do not contain a "_".

The following query works, but searches all the files. I want to modify it so that it only searches lectio1.xml and lectio2.xml, not the files with "_"'s

```
for $file in collection('/db/SCTA/')
    for $p at $i in $file/tei:TEI//tei:p
        let $param1:= request:get-parameter('param1', 'oyta')
        let $pid := data($p/@xml:id)
        let $fs := data($file/tei:TEI/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div/@xml:id)
        let $title := $file/tei:TEI/tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title/text()

        where ($p[contains(., $param1)])
        order by $fs
        return 
        <p>{$fs}: {$title}: {$pid}: {$p/text()}</p>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer that relied solely on the functions available to you in the XQuery spec would have you filter the result of the `collection()` function by parsing the results of the `base-uri()` function on all collection contents. For example:

```
for $file in collection('/db/SCTA')[not(contains(replace(base-uri(.), '^.*/([^/]+?)$', '$1'), '_'))]
```

As it appears you're using eXist, we can use one of eXist's utility functions, namely `util:document-name()`, to make this a little easier:

```
for $file in collection('/db/SCTA')[not(contains(util:document-name(.), '_'))]
```

For the function documentation on `util:document-name()`, see http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#document-name.1.

--

While you didn't ask for advice on opportunities for optimizing your query, I see some aspects of your code which are worthy of discussion.

Unless you have a reason beyond what is shown here in the code sample, you might consider consolidating your two nested FLWOR expressions into one:

```
let $param1:= request:get-parameter('param1', 'oyta')
let $docs := collection('/db/SCTA')[not(contains(util:document-name(.), '_'))]

for $p in $docs//tei:p[contains(., $param1)]
let $pid := $p/@xml:id/string()
let $fs := $p/ancestor::tei:div[last()]/@xml:id/string()
let $title := root($p)/tei:TEI/tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title/string()
order by $fs
return 
    <p>{$fs}: {$title}: {$pid}: {$p/string()}</p>
```

Notice here that:

1. We get the value of `$param1` once, rather than again during each iteration of the FLWOR expression.
2. We identify the documents in a `let` clause rather than a `for`, since we are really interested in iterating over the sequence of all `tei:p` elements *period*, not the `tei:p` elements *within each document*.
3. We leverage eXist's [structural index](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/indexing.xml#structuralidx) to descend directly to the `tei:p` elements, rather than specifying any intermediate child axis steps; we use the XPath ancestor axis to reach up to the `p`'s highest/outer-most `tei:div`; and we use the `root()` function to jump up to the document node in order to get back down to the `tei:teiHeader` (alternatively, use `$p/preceding::tei:titleStmt/tei:title`). For more, see [Prefer short paths](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/tuning.xml#D2.2.6.2).
4. We use a predicate rather than a `where` clause. As stated [here in eXist's documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/tuning.xml#D2.2.6.6), predicates allow eXist's query optimizer to squeeze more performance out of a FLWOR expression. Not that you can't use `where`; just best to steer clear in eXist, at least.
5. We use the `string()` function instead of `data()` and `text()`.  In some ways, this could be seen as a stylistic choice, but after reading articles like Evan Lenz's [text() is a code smell](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell), I prefer the precision of `string()` when I want to get the string value of an attribute or a single string value of an element which may contain mixed content.  (The article mostly covers `text()`, but see the discussion of `data()` in [this thread](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell#comment-407618423) in the comments.)

One step I didn't demonstrate here is applying a full text index to your `tei:p` element to speed and improve the search function of this query. If you defined a full text index on `tei:p`, you could change your `for` clause to:

```
for $p in $docs//tei:p[ft:query(., $param1)]
```

And then `param1` could use the full power of [Lucene's query parser syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html), including stemming, case insensitivity (contains is case sensitive), wildcarding, proximity, etc.  But full text indexing is covered in eXist's documentation: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/lucene.xml.

Comment: that's amazingly helpful. I've been mostly working my way through this trial and error style. Steps 1-5 will be a great advance.

Comment: That turned a 3 second query into a 0.17s query. Looking forward to getting together :)